# command "ipython" conflict with anaconda and /usr/bin

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I created an anaconda virtual environment and installed packages related to jupyter and ipython.
But when I type command "ipython" or "jupyter notebook", ipython or jupyter notebook get started from '/usr/bin/', not from my conda environment '/opt/conda/envs/pytorch/bin/' where they're supposed to be from.

How can I start them from conda environment instead of /usr/bin ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate your environment first:

```
conda activate pytorch
```

see the conda user guide here:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Comment: I am runninng those commands within (pytorch) environment activated. Other commands like 'python' seems to work fine with correct path but only ipython and jupyter notebook